# When is the file uploaded using FileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

If you put a asp:FileUpload control on a page, browse to a file, and then submit the form. is the file uploaded to the server when you submit the form?

I have seen loads of examples of file uploads where the file is passed to a filestream and uploaded.

I don't understand what is happening when. After you click your Upload button, the code is being executed on the server. So the file (file name? file path?) supplied by the FileUpload control using FileUpload.PostedFile (or the httpFileCollection) ... is this uploaded when the form is submitted? How can the server gain access to the file on the client machine so it can be uploaded using a filestream.

I don't get it. I keep reading that the filestream passes (can pass) the data in chunks - helping to bypass restrictions on file size etc. but, as I said above, when/how is the file uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 1):

The `<asp:FileUpload>` control renders an `<input type="file">`, and sets the form's content type to `multipart/form-data`.

When the browser submits a `<form>` with an `<input type="file">`, it will send the entire file to the server in the HTTP POST (this is part of the content-type).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - what is the point of all the filestream stuff? Why not just save the HttpPostedFile file?

And I have been looking at code to report the progress of the upload - and, again, it all seems to use FileStream - but how can this work if the file is uploaded in one go to the server when the form is posted?

Comment: Is the code here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106511/Multiple-file-uploads-with-progress-bar-using-clas

actually monitoring the file as it moves from the browser to the server?

Answer (score 1):

When you click upload, the html form is submitted and a post request is send to the server.

It does not actually send you a "file" object of some kind that you can directly store, just the content of the file in bytes and some metadata, like the filename.

On the server, you have to handle this request: You have to read the bytes into an actual file to properly store it.

In the example that you mention, this is what the HttpPostedFile is used for.

Comment: HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[0];
    string FilePath = hpf.FileName;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

You say the 'content of the file in bytes' is sent to the server when you post. In the code above, if the file content has been sent to the server, what is the point of sending it to a filestream, when you can just as easily do this:
hpf.SaveAs(path + ReturnValue.ToString() + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));

Comment: Both reading the file stream into a file and using the `SaveAs` method stores the bytes into a file. The difference is that with the file stream approach you get some information about the progress. And this is what the example is about.